# How to add elements to jQuery UI accordion header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to add а html table into accordion header. Is that possible and how can I do this without crew up UI styles?

I saw that UI makes `h3` tags to act like `div`, but when I add a table into it and float it right, it broke the below `div` styles.

There is the HTML i've add to the header:

```
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-header-active ui-accordion-icons accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" id="ui-accordion-league_accordian-header-0" aria-controls="ui-accordion-league_accordian-panel-0" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span> Test  
    <table style="float: right;margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</h3>
```

Comment: you will need to use a clearfix solution like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v4b9Y/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding 'clear: both' to the css for the element directly under your table, it's probably being affected by the float in your table